# retrieve the storage usage for a Linux Virtual Machine using the Azure REST API

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, metrics, azure-management-api

I try to get storage used for virtual machine. I just found endpoint that get total of storge

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/vmSizes?api-version=2017-12-01
```

How i can get the memory usage or storage usage??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the metrics to find the CPU percentage used by virtual machine. Find the supported metrics for Virtual machines [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines).

Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-rest-api-walkthrough) to get the required metric value by specifying the metric name

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/{resource-provider-namespace}/{resource-type}/{resource-name}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?$filter={filter}&api-version={apiVersion}